# regex c part of IP

Tags: c, regex

How write regular expression?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>
int main () {
regex_t regex;
int reti;
char msgbuf[100];
const char *regIp = "^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){1,3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?){0,1}$";
reti = regcomp(&regex, regIp, 0);
regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
printf("Regex compile: %s.", msgbuf);
reti = regexec(&regex, "192.168.100", 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti){
    puts("MUTCH!!");
    } else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
    puts("No mutch");
    } else {
    regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
    printf("Regex match failed: %s.", msgbuf);
    }
}
```

I have *No mutch* .

I try mask braces, as

```
^\\(?:\\(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\\)\\.\\)\\{1,3\\}\\(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\\)\\{0,1\\}$
```

But not matches again.

Thanks advance.

Comment: You need to pass `REG_EXTENDED` to the `regcomp` method and escape the dot with 2 backslashes.

Comment: I put <code>1</code> instead of REG_EXTENDED and got <em>Segmentation fault</em>

Comment: See https://ideone.com/cuQNbS. I forgot: you must replace non-capturing groups with *capturing* ones since POSIX regex does not support non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `REG_EXTENDED` with `regcomp` and double the backslash before `.`.

Replace the two lines with `regIp` initialization and `reti` assignment in your code with

```
const char *regIp = "^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\\.){1,3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)?$";
reti = regcomp(&regex, regIp, REG_EXTENDED);
// => Regex compile: Success.MATCH!!
```

See the [C demo](https://ideone.com/cuQNbS)

With `REG_EXTENDED`, POSIX ERE syntax will be allowed in the pattern (so that `{m,n}` quantifier could be used without escaping the curly braces), and it will also allow the use of `$`. The literal regex escape `\` must be defined with a double backslash in a C string literal.

Note that you must replace non-capturing groups with *capturing* ones since POSIX regex does not support non-capturing groups. So, all `(?:...)` should be turned into `(...)`.

Comment: Thanks!! It's work for me!
A special thank you for the clarification!